# WCF DataContract DataMember order

Tags: c#, wcf

How would one order the properties within DataMember classes?
I am able to order the DataMember's at the top level, but not the properties within the child classes.
For example:

My ServiceContract

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    WcfResponse CallMe(WcfRequest request);
}
```

My Service

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public WcfResponse CallMe(WcfRequest request)
    {
        return new WcfResponse();
    }
}
```

My DataContract classes

```
[DataContract]
public class WcfRequest
{
    [Required]
    [DataMember]
    public Header Header { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataMember]
    public Footer Footer { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class WcfResponse
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Status { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Errors { get; set; }

    public WcfResponse()
    {
        Status = "FAILED";
        Errors = null;
    }
}
```

So that when I use a tool like SoapUI I can see that the request object is serialized in alphabetical order (as per WCF default):

```
     <tem:request>
        <edf:Footer>
           <edf:IsComplete>?</edf:IsComplete>
           <edf:Submitted>?</edf:Submitted>
        </edf:Footer>
        <edf:Header>
           <edf:CompanyName>?</edf:CompanyName>
           <edf:UserName>?</edf:UserName>
        </edf:Header>
     </tem:request>
```

If I change my DataContract to use the Order parameter I can reorder my properties:

```
[DataContract]
public class WcfRequest
{
    [Required]
    [DataMember(Order = 0)]
    public Header Header { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public Footer Footer { get; set; }
}
```

And updating the Service definition will give:

```
     <tem:request>
        <edf:Header>
           <edf:CompanyName>?</edf:CompanyName>
           <edf:UserName>?</edf:UserName>
        </edf:Header>
        <edf:Footer>
           <edf:IsComplete>?</edf:IsComplete>
           <edf:Submitted>?</edf:Submitted>
        </edf:Footer>
     </tem:request>
```

As we expect.
My question is to ask how to order the properties of the Header & Footer classes in the same way please.
If I attempt the following:

```
public class Header
{
    [DataMember(Order = 3)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}
public class Footer
{
    [DataMember(Order = 5)]
    public DateTime Submitted { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 6)]
    public bool IsComplete { get; set; }
}
```

The properties do not reorder and are still alphabetically ordered.

Comment: Your header and footer don't have a `DataContract` attribute.

Comment: Crikey. It took a while to write the question am kind of happy this simple omission is the reason. Attribute applied and issue sorted. Thank you! @CodeCaster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your header and footer don't have a DataContract attribute. – CodeCaster